# JQuery UI 1.8.23 copy paste issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

We are using following JQuery code (JSF) to invoke Autocomplete. Everthing seems to work fine when user keys in data but when user copies and pastes Autocomplete will work only in second attempt. I am testing following code in IE 8. Any inputs are appreciated

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () { 
    $(document).on('keyup.autocomplete','##{resp.workItemResponse.wiResponseId}', function() {
        $('##{resp.workItemResponse.wiResponseId}').autocomplete({
            minLength: 3,
            source: function( request, response){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: "/iaportal/autoCompleteServlet",
                    cache: false,
                    delay: 200,
                    data: {
                        'respId':'#{resp.workItemResponse.wiResponseId}',
                        'type': '#{autoCompleteType}',
                        'term':request.term
                    },
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data){
                        response($.map(data.acctNum, function (item) {
                            return {                                
                                label: item.label,
                                value: item.label
                            }
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function(message){
                        alert("error "+message);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var selectedObj = ui.item;
                var text = selectedObj.value;
                $('.autoComplete#{resp.workItemResponse.wiResponseId}').attr('value', text);
                $('.autoComplete#{resp.workItemResponse.wiResponseId}').trigger('change'); 
            }
        });
        $('##{resp.workItemResponse.wiResponseId}').keyup(function(){
            var text = this.value;
            if(text == '' || text.length == 0){
                $('.autoComplete#{resp.workItemResponse.wiResponseId}').attr('value', "");
                $('.autoComplete#{resp.workItemResponse.wiResponseId}').trigger('change');
            }
        });
    }); // on Ends

    var textElem;
    $(document).on('paste','##{resp.workItemResponse.wiResponseId}',function() {
        textElem = this;
        setTimeout(invokeOnPaste , 100); 
    });  

    function invokeOnPaste(){
        var text = $(textElem).val();
        if(text.length == 14){ 
            $('.autoComplete#{resp.workItemResponse.wiResponseId}').attr('value', text);
            $('.autoComplete#{resp.workItemResponse.wiResponseId}').trigger('change'); 
        } else if(text.length != 0){
            $('##{resp.workItemResponse.wiResponseId}').trigger('search','autocomplete');
        } 
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Clipboard access is restricted in Javascript for all browsers except IE (and FireFox with enabled config option.) You would need to bind to something else, like `keyup` for `Ctrl+V` paste. Binding to the Context Menu paste  in a cross-browser compatible way is not possible, as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks Serj Sagan . I could fix copy and paste issue (CTRL + V and mouse context paste) with JQuery Plugin : https://gist.github.com/mkelly12/424774 . We want this working in IE8  and it does work with this plugin.I presume this would work in other browsers too.

Comment: Yes, but it uses flash to do it in other browsers